# How to check for "don't care" values when checking if an element exists in a set of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this leetcode problem: [Time Based Key Value Store](https://leetcode.com/problems/time-based-key-value-store/)

I have a set of tuples represented (timestamp, value). I want a while loop to run until there's an element in the set that has the necessary timestamp. The problem is I don't know the value of the tuple, so I ideally want to use something that represents a "don't care" value

So this doesn't work

```
def get(self, key: str, timestamp: int) -> str:
        if key not in self.map: return ""
        while (timestamp, _) not in self.map[key] and timestamp >= 0:
            timestamp -= 1
        return self.map[key][(timestamp, _)][1] if timestamp >= 0 else ""
```

Whats the easiest way to go about this and why doesn't the _ operator not work? Isn't is supposed to be used for don't care values?

Rest of class for context:

```
class TimeMap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}

    def set(self, key: str, value: str, timestamp: int) -> None:
        if key not in self.map:
            self.map[key] = set([(timestamp, value)])
        else:
            self.map[key].add((timestamp, value))
```

Comment: There is no `_` operator. You seem to be thinking of syntax specific to the `match` statement.

Comment: This isn't a job for a set. You need an ordered data structure.

Comment: Maybe you find a answer [here, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527919/12621346)

Comment: Go back and reread the problem description. then think about creating a data structure that is based on a dict of dicts of the form {timestamp:{key: val}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_` isn't an operator for "don't care". It's often used as a variable name for things we don't care about, so if you have a function that outputs a tuple but you only care about one of the values, you can use `_` as a variable, but `_` still stores data:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    return (1, a, a*b, a*b*c)

(_,_,x,_) = func(1,2,3)

print(x) # prints 2
print(_) # prints 6
```

I'd recommend a different structure, but that's not your question. Given the rest of your class, I'd recommend converting the set to a dictionary when checking:

```
def get(self, key: str, timestamp: int) -> str:
    if key not in self.map: return ""
    dict = {time : val for (time, val) in self.map[key]}
    while timestamp not in dict and timestamp >= 0:
        timestamp -= 1
    return dict[timestamp] if timestamp >= 0 else ""
```